# How to redirect to a new page using auto form and iron router?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, routes

So I have built an auto form using autoform. I want to redirect to a new page displaying new templates after the form has been submitted. How can I do that ??

Here is my html  code:
    
      The Ultimatum Game

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar"><h1>The Ultimatum Game</h1></div>
 {{> player}}
  </div>
</body>

<template name="player">
  {{> quickForm collection="PlayersList" id="insertList" type="insert"       }}
</template>
```

How to redirect it to a new Q/A page after a user submits it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a redirect in event handler:

```
Template.player.events({
  'submit form': function(e, t) {
    Router.go('newPath');
  },
});
```

Comment: Am is supposed to add this to my router.js file or the main.js file considering the html is present in main.html ???

Comment: A good practice would be to move the template code to player.html and player.js files.

Comment: But does the submit form event work for AutoForm package?? I tried doing it but I got errors.